# App Freezing when terminated and launched again

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have an application which seems to be freezing after I terminate and re-launch the app.
To be more clear when I am running my app (on Device connected to mac), with **Xcode** launching it, it's working fine every time. But when I disconnect **USB** from Xcode, and terminate and launch app again it freezes my app.

NOTE-: It sometimes happen after doing this process for 4-5 time.

I am building my app on Xcode `11.3.1 (11C504)` and my device OS version is `13.3.1`.

This app was originally designed using older version of `Xcode (10.2.1)` or older. I am not able to debug this issue because it never happen when running from Xcode.

Can anyone help me here? Is this an OS issue?

Also, is there any way I can figure out if it's happening due to code?

> Issue -: My app reaches Home screen after waiting on splash screen for
>   2-3 sec, and after that I can't perform any UI task.

It later on works fine, after I terminate it again from frozen state.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are really asking here but make sure that the mac and device are on the same network and it should show an option to wirelessly connect the two devices. If you are doing it wired you aren't able to unplug USB and still show app